# Composer and registering Autoloader

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

According to https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master it infers I don't register autoloader if I install PHPWord via composer. See:

```
It is recommended that you install the PHPWord library through composer. To do so, add the following lines to your composer.json.

{
    "require": {
       "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master"
    }
}
Alternatively, you can download the latest release from the releases page. In this case, you will have to register the autoloader.

require_once 'path/to/PhpWord/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
```

(specifically **In this case, you will have to register the autoloader.**).

However, if I install via Composer skip these lines

```
require_once 'path/to/PhpWord/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader' not found in /Users/snowcrash/Developer/Code/PHP/PHPWord_Projects/test/basic_eg.php on line 3
```

So, my question is - do I need to require and register `Autoloader` with Composer?

If so, is the documentation incorrect or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install it via Composer you still always have to `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'` in your project. That is the Composer's autoloader.

The difference is that the Composer's autoloader can be used for all libraries you include later, not just for the one you want right now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the index.php file in public directory.
All you need is a clean index.php file, so you can create a new directory where you can install new laravel. From the new laravel directory, copy the index.php file and replace in the original repository.
It works for me.. :)